# Fastest way to add pre-existing static HTML page to a React/Gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby

I have a simple project working nicely using JSX / React / Gatsby.

I have a pre-existing page (think landing page) in HTML in another project, quite complex, nicely styled using Bootstrap 4, let's call it LandingPage.html and an associated LandingPage.css.

I would like to add the landing page to my Gatsby site.  So that for example when navigating to localhost:3000/LandingPage.html the landing page gets shown, properly styled etc.

I am not clear whether I have to fully convert my pre-existing HTML into a react component / JSX?
Or whether I can just serve the LandingPage.html (and associated styling files) by placing it somewhere sensible in my Gatsby project structure?
Or whether I have to create a react "wrapper" that at "run time" reads in the content of LandingPage.html and LandingPage.css?

Note: I've tried just putting the LandingPage.html and LandingPage.css into the /public folder and actually that does work!  So maybe I've answered my own question.  But is the the right way to do it?

Comment: Are you able to navigate to the other routes during development with `gatsby develop`. When i place an index.html file as my landing page in `/static`, i cant now go to `/about` or any other route. I have to first build the project, serve the static file, then i can navigate around. Know how to work around that?

Answer (score 14):

As of Gatsby v2 (don't know about previous versions), it is maybe more consistent to add the file to the `/static` folder.

According to [the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-project-structure/#folders), the `/public` folder is meant to be generated automatically when building the site and should be added to `.gitignore`.

Files added to the `/static` folder will be copied to `/public` when building the site so it should have the same effect. More info [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/).