# How to add static files to gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I currently have a working Gatsby site, but I want to include static html/css files to the site.

example -
I have currentSite.com but I want to add currentSite.com/moreStuff/evenMoreStuff using a folder of static stuff I have.

How do I go about this with minimal editing to my gatsby files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the static files to gatsby's static folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to add pre-existing static HTML page to a React/Gatsby site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895443/fastest-way-to-add-pre-existing-static-html-page-to-a-react-gatsby-site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your Gatsby project root is a `/static` folder. If it isn't there you can create it.
2. Place your static HTML in there. It should have the path `/static/moreStuff/evenMoreStuff`,
3. `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build`.

You're done.

Make sure not to create a page in your `/pages` directory with the same name or route as your static html files.

Comment: This question is a couple of years old now, but I'm trying to do the exact same thing with a new Gatsby site I've just created using v4.x.
The site I'm trying to include is an existing Storybook that has been exported as static files.  But when I try to access it via Gatsby it says page not found, but if I try an image it's fine.
e.g.  http://localhost:8000/storybook-docs/index.html - Page Not Found
http://localhost:8000/storybook-docs/logo.png - Loads image

Comment: @Cuong The storybook application on localhost might not have the appropriate variables or access set for the static folder. I can't really help since I barely use storybook. I would suggest to ask a dedicated question with the 'storebook' and 'gatsby' tag like "How to access static folder in a Storybook application with Gatsby".